# Apply custom font to RecyclerView items within a Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

How do I apply a font style to the items in a `RecyclerView` that are displayed within a `Fragment`?

Comment: Are you wanting to apply the font style to the `TextView`s in each item?

Comment: yes exactly. view item is (image and TextView).

Comment: Also, do you want to change the **font** or **font style** e.g. **bold**. Your title says font but your question says font style.

Comment: Sorry ,just font only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to change the font of your `TextView`s in your `Fragment`, by default, starting from Android 4.1, [Roboto](https://material.google.com/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html) fonts are used by default. You can change the type of that font by using:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

If you want to use your own font, which can be troublesome and can result in a memory leak, you can't specify that font in XML. Instead, you'll have to change it programmatically like so:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview03);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
text.setTypeface(tf);
```

> **Remember:** The fonts must be stored in your `res/assets` directory. You can create a subfolder and called it `fonts` within that directory. Make sure your font files are of supported formats like `.otf` and `.ttf`

If you want to change the font style, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextStyle) page, you can use this:

```
<TextView android:textStyle="normal" /> // normal
<TextView android:textStyle="bold" /> // bold
<TextView android:textStyle="italic" /> // italic
```

Tell me how you go.